# NSTextField in status bar doesn't want to receive focus

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, user-interface

For some reson sometimes a NSTextField I'm using in Status Bar menu doesn't always allow me to input text. I click it and nothing happens as if it was disabled. Upon restarting program it works again. I don't do anything with it, it's just created in the interface builder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because no NSWindow contains the NSTextField. The NSWindow sets the first responder when the window gets the main window. The NSStatusBar is global. It's never focused so your textfield only will be focused in the very beginning.

I'm not sure if there's a way to solve this problem in a nice way. You might try to set the first responder manually. You could also add a [global event monitor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSEvent_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Example:

```
[NSEvent addGlobalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSKeyDownMask handler:^(NSEvent* incoming) {
  [textfield setStringValue:[incoming characters]];
}];
```

Note: This is a very bad way to fix this problem. I'd first try to set the NSTextField manually as a first responder if this is possible.

Comment: You probably don't want to use `setStringValue:`, otherwise you could only have one letter in the field at a time!

Comment: No, `-appendString:` is void, you want `-stringByAppendingString:`.

Comment: It's [textfield setStringValue:[textfield.stringValue stringByAppendingString:[incoming characters]]];